# Passing a parameter to a link inside an < a > href tag using only HTML

Tags: javascript, html, url, tags, parameter-passing

I decided to resubmit this question because I probably was not clear on my problem and my overall objective.

I am currently working with a website using only HTML.  I have variables being passed in the URL that are read by a javascript and I then take the parameter for each variable and populate it into a Google javascript.

JS reading the URL:

```
function gup(name) { 
var params = {}; 
var parts = (window.location.search || '').split(/[&?]/); 
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) { 
var eq = parts[i].indexOf('='); 
if (eq < 0) continue; 
params[decodeURIComponent(parts[i].substring(0, eq))] 
= decodeURIComponent(parts[i].substring(eq+1)); 
} 
return Object.hasOwnProperty.call(params, name) 
? params[name] : null; 
}
```

The variable to be written to the second JS:

```
var keyValue1 = gup( 'pid1' );
```

The portion of the Google JS that is written to:

```
GA_googleAddAttr("pid1", keyValue1);
```

All of this has been working quite well for me.  Those parameters are passed into Google ads but I still have several links on the page that do not have the '?pid1=' variable attached.  I would like to be able to do one of the following:

1. Take the parameter from the variable 'pid1' and pass it into a link located in a < a > tag.  ( NOTE:  I do have multiple variables, example.com/index.html?pid1=abc&pid2=def&pid3=ghi )
2. Strip from the URL, starting with the ? and everything thereafter and attach it to one link or all links located in a < a > tag(s) on the page.
3. Strip from the URL, starting with the ? and only a selected set of variable(s) and attach it to one link or all links located in a < a > tag(s) on the page.

Very important note, my JS knowledge is limited to asking questions and taking what I get and trying to figure it out from there, which is what I am hoping to do here.  Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure if the `<a>` tag is already on the page, but if it is:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
     if(links[i].href === "http://foo.com/index.html?pid1=") {
         links[i].href = links[i].href + gup( 'pid1' );
     }

}
```

Comment: Please excuse my limited knowledge of JS.  I am not exactly sure how to implement 'var links', or rather call it from the < a > tag.  One thing that came to mind, the < a > example was not a fixed url, used across the website but rather an example.  Perhaps it would be best for a parse of everything after the '?' and added to a specific link and/or all < a > tags.